# move a background endless in swift 4

Tags: swift, background, sprite-kit

Hi i'm trying to move a background endlessly, but i have a little problem when i simulate the code.

This is my code

```
didMove(to view: SKView) {

    for i  in 0...1 {
        let backgroundNEW = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "New_Background")
        backgroundNEW.size = self.size
        backgroundNEW.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5 , y: 0)
        backgroundNEW.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width  ,  y: self.size.height  * CGFloat(i))
        backgroundNEW.zPosition = -1
        backgroundNEW.name = "test"
        addChild(backgroundNEW)
    }
}
```

and

```
 var lastUpdateTime : TimeInterval = 0
 var deltaFrameTime : TimeInterval = 0
 var amountToMovePerSecond : CGFloat = 200.0

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval){

    if lastUpdateTime == 0{
        lastUpdateTime = currentTime
    }
    else {
        deltaFrameTime = currentTime - lastUpdateTime
        lastUpdateTime = currentTime
    }

    let amountToMoveBackground =  amountToMovePerSecond * CGFloat(deltaFrameTime)

    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "test") {
        backgroundNEW, stop in

        backgroundNEW.position.x -= amountToMoveBackground

        if backgroundNEW.position.x < -self.size.height{
            backgroundNEW.position.x += self.size.height*2
        }
    }
}
```

i got this simulation : https://gyazo.com/63ce327ce9bc0a14199f411ac187de25

my problem is the black background i dont know how i can replace it to do the background moving endless .

Comment: This is super easy. I'll post my code from my game to show you how I did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my code I am using to scroll a background infinitely (assuming you are using SpriteKit?) You need two backgrounds to give it the look and feel of an infinitely scrolling background. I updated it to work for 3 backgrounds to provide an infinite scroll.

outside your `didMove(toView:)` method

```
var bg = SKSpriteNode()
var bg2 = SKSpriteNode()
var bg3 = SKSpriteNode()

var parallax = SKAction()
```

setting up your backgrounds inside your `didMove(toView:)` method

```
bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "texture")
bg.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y:0)
bg.zPosition = 3
bg.size = CGSize(width:Int, height:Int) //make sure to set the width to self.frame.size.width, the height can be anything

bg2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "texture")
bg2.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y:0)
bg2.zPosition = 3
bg2.size = CGSize(width:Int, height:Int) //make sure to set the width to self.frame.size.width, the height can be anything

bg3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "texture")
bg3.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width + bg2.position.x, y:0)
bg3.zPosition = 3
bg3.size = CGSize(width:Int, height:Int) //make sure to set the width to self.frame.size.width, the height can be anything

self.addChild(bg)
self.addChild(bg2)
self.addChild(bg3)
```

Now to handle the scrolling of the backgrounds

```
parallax = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: -self.frame.size.width, dy: 0), duration: 20)) 
//higher duration moves it slower, lower duration moves it faster

bg.run(parallax)
bg2.run(parallax)
bg3.run(parallax)
```

Finally, in the `update(currentTime:)` method that updates before each frame

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
    if bg.position.x <= -self.frame.size.width {
        bg.position.x = self.frame.size.width * 2
        //this ensures that your backgrounds line up perfectly 
    }
    if bg2.position.x <= -self.frame.size.width {
        bg2.position.x = self.frame.size.width * 2
        //this ensures that your backgrounds line up perfectly
    }
    if bg3.position.x <= -self.frame.size.width {
        bg3.position.x = self.frame.size.width * 2
        //this ensures that your backgrounds line up perfectly
    }
}
```

If you have any questions, ask them so I can help you out.

Comment: hello . thanks your reply i tryied your code but he didn't worked  well for me ,  
I got this https://gyazo.com/bcb09e5605469762148d4e7cc9b8286f 
I replaced the 
bg = SKSpriteNode(texture: "texture") by 

let  background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background")
    And let background2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background2") 
for the size I got this      
   background2.size CGSize(width:self.frame.size.width,height:self.frame.size.height)
 do you know how i can fix it  i use Xcode 9  and Sprite kit

Comment: Its working, you just need to add a 3rd background. I will edit my answer above to show you how to add a 3rd background.

Comment: My edited answer has been tested and works perfectly.