# Black Line in Vertical Moving Swift Background

Tags: swift, background, sprite-kit

i have a Problem and need your help.

I have modified a code from this old thread
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162476/move-a-background-endless-in-swift-4/52312016#52312016)

That i get a vertical moving background. The code works nice. But i have between every moving background image a tiny black line.

looks like something overlaps. But why?
It would be nice if anyone can help me to fix this error.

Thanks alot

Here is my code:

```
 var bg = SKSpriteNode()
 var bg2 = SKSpriteNode()
 var bg3 = SKSpriteNode()

 var parallax = SKAction()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {



 bg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "back1")
 bg.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
 bg.zPosition = 1
 bg.size = self.size

 bg2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "back2")
 bg2.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2+self.size.height)

 bg2.zPosition = 1
 bg2.size = self.size

 bg3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "back3")
 bg3.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y:self.size.height/2+self.size.height+self.size.height)
 bg3.zPosition = 1

 bg3.size = self.size
 self.addChild(bg)
 self.addChild(bg2)
 self.addChild(bg3)

 parallax = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -self.frame.size.height), duration: 4))


 bg.run(parallax)
 bg2.run(parallax)
 bg3.run(parallax)}


override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

 // Called before each frame is rendered
 if bg.position.y <= -self.frame.size.height {

      bg.position.y = self.frame.size.height*2
      //this ensures that your backgrounds line up perfectly
 }

 if bg2.position.y <= -self.frame.size.height {
      bg2.position.y = self.frame.size.height*2
      //this ensures that your backgrounds line up perfectly
 }

 if bg3.position.y <= -self.frame.size.height {
      bg3.position.y = self.frame.size.height*2
      //this ensures that your backgrounds line up perfectly
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are having floating point rounding issues. The concept of 1/2 a pixel does not exist, so when you get to a position like 12.5, the system needs to either make it 12, or 13.

Now, since decimal does not convert well to fractal binary you are going to end up with numbers like 12.499929932092434234234324 and 12.50000000342423423424, but as far as you know, it is still 12.5.

To fix this,  you need to force your position to always round in the same direction, either up or down.

You are probably going to want to round down since most grids work in a 0 based indexing system.

To fix your code,  we need to do:

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
 bg.position.x.round(.down)
 bg.position.y.round(.down)
 bg2.position.x.round(.down)
 bg2.position.y.round(.down)
 bg3.position.x.round(.down)
 bg3.position.y.round(.down)

// Called before each frame is rendered
 if bg.position.y <= -self.frame.size.height {

      bg.position.y += self.frame.size.height*2
      //this ensures that your backgrounds line up perfectly
 }

 if bg2.position.y <= -self.frame.size.height {
      bg2.position.y += self.frame.size.height*2
      //this ensures that your backgrounds line up perfectly
 }

 if bg3.position.y <= -self.frame.size.height {
      bg3.position.y += self.frame.size.height*2
      //this ensures that your backgrounds line up perfectly
 }

}
```

Now of course, as you get better with development, you are going to want to move these types of things outside of your update function.  Eventually, you will want to perform these checks when position changes, this way if nothing is moving, you are not needlessly  executing these lines of code to fix a position that does not need fixing.

Edit:

Noticed another problem,  you need to do += the height, not = height, because if you are at -1, that will also cause a gap, since you are not accounting for the line of height - 1 (Basically, your first image ends at height - 2, and your new image starts at height, making a gap at height - 1)

Comment: Hi Knight, if i use the piece of code for the round down i got these error message. 'inout CGFloat' is not convertible to 'CGFloat' Really strange , cause for me the code seems right

Comment: Yeah that is my fault, you should be able to round without having to reassign it

Comment: I have updated my code, round is a mutating function

Comment: also, check my Edit notes for a new problem I noticed

Comment: Thanks, your code i try the new one. Now i got no black line but. But if it comes to the update function i have for 1 or 2 second a half black screen and the it will be updated to new background. But i can see it . Do you know what i mean.

Comment: I dont understand how your code actually works, because you need 2 backgrounds per layer to make it scroll (or 1 background  that is the same texture repeated twice)

Comment: no problem , i think i will change the code. Think its better. But thanks for your help :)